# choosing package repository

Tags: packages, miktex

I'm trying to install the floatflt package and I'm having trouble. I am using MikTex package manager and when I try to install the package, it says that "the remote package repository is not online. You have to choose another repository." How do I choose a repository without it saying that it isn't valid?

Comment: Following <http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/updating.html>, do you get the message no matter what repository you select? Have you checked your internet connection?

Comment: That link gives me a 404 error. I keep getting the following:

Permission denied: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.8\miktex\config\df2c24cb21984fa85003c1ecc818ff83.fndb

Comment: Quoting from miktex.org: "MikTeX2.8 is considered out-of-date but to be kept alive for a while for Windows 2000 users." MikTeX 2.9 has a lot of goodies that version 2.8 is missing; assuming you're computer isn't still running Windows2000, you may want to consider updating your MikTeX distribution.

Comment: I think that's a good idea, it turned out that deleting that file removed the error.