# "the remote package repository is not registered"

Tags: packages

I'm getting this error and don't know how to fix it.  Is there some way to specify a different package repository?  I'm no expert on MikTex so I was hoping there was something easy.  I tried running the install file again to see if there was an option but it won't overwrite/modify the old installation.

This is MikTex 2.9 on 64-bit Windows 7 Service Pack 1.

The two prior questions ([package install changepage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63483/package-install-changepage) and [choosing package repository](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63570/choosing-package-repository)) that seem to mention my problem were both closed by admins as "too localized".  :-(

Comment: Go to Update MiKTeX wizard, select ``I want to get updated packages from remote repository``. The select ``Let me choose a remote package repository`` and then click on ``Connection settings``. This will open window with list of all CTAN mirror, from which you can update your packages. If you like to obtain particular package, than use ``MiKTeX Package Manager``. There you also can change remote repository.

Comment: Zarko, when I click on "Connection settings", a small dialog offering the option of using a "proxy server" and asking for an "Address" appears, not a list of all CTAN mirrors...

Comment: Correction: there is no need to click on "Connection settings", which opens a small dialog offering the option of using a "proxy server" and asking for an "Address" appears, not a list of all CTAN mirrors. To see the list, click on "Next".

Comment: I tried to change the server url, it works for me ... see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56783/how-can-i-change-the-package-repository

Answer (score 1):

Go to Repository>Synchronize and synchronize your packages. Worked like a charm for me. Apparently this could be caused by having an outdated Miktek version, but I didn't need to update this.

Comment: I am having the same problem as the questioner, and this solution does not work for me. I get the same error when I do this.

Answer (score 0):

If synchronize does not work, then go to -> change package directory, and tick -> packages shall be installed on the internet, then you can synchronize your packages and repository.

Comment: Does this answer the question? As far as I can tell, it doesn't. But I don't know much about MikTeX.

Comment: If you do not know MikTeX much, how can you tell it does not help? Have you tried it? Lazy comment.

Comment: I was trying to prompt you to explain how this is supposed to address the problem, since it is not obvious to me and, so, probably not obvious to at least some other readers. What underlying problem does your suggestion address?

Comment: Look at the first answer and its reply

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem. Open the MiKTeX console, go to the 'Packages' tab, and change the 'Retrieve from:' option to 'Random package repository on the Internet'.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your MiKTeX console (you can reach it from the start menu) and then click on updates -> install form: a random package repo on the internet. This worked for me. Otherwise you have to look for their new url repo.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to change the url of the update server, and it works ... see [How can I change the package repository?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56783/how-can-i-change-the-package-repository)